# Cannot detect wireless driver intel ac wireless 9560 [logs included]

Tags: iwlwifi

Currently using Ubuntu 18.04, and my wireless driver is not being detected.

I've included a [wireless diagnosis log](https://pastebin.com/MWEFMMCq).

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    6.212724] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    6.212724] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:6988:0d8892f2
[    6.224583] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.229811] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[    6.230540] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.230547] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.230552] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-37.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.230557] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-36.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.230562] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-35.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.236670] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 34.0.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.248314] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    7.264081] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x2477
[    7.264084] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    7.276165] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi` returns no output.

Comment: I expect that it wants but is missing firmware. Let's try to find out which. Please edit your question to add the result of two terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555: OP added the requested info and it looks like the driver found a firmware and loaded it happily.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed this morning that Update Manager installed a later version of the package *linux-firmware*. I suggest that you obtain a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

I suspect that *linux-firmware* will be upgraded. After the upgrade, my firmware files include:

```
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
```

Reboot so that -38 loads instead of -34 as before. Check the log:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Is the alarming message gone?

> iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110

Your wireless should be working now.

Comment: gave that a go same error messages - Im suspecting it could be a hardware problem - tried using the wifi module on windows as well and seems like its failing as well

Comment: I'm having this issue in Ubuntu live environment, but for me, it works fine in Windows, I have a connection, but installer/live environment cannot connect to internet 9560. I'm hesitant to install if I can't get wi fi working, any ideas?

Comment: @edencorbin Please start your own new question. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @chili555 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054012/driver-intel-ac-wireless-9560-ubuntu-18/1054016?noredirect=1#comment1723094_1054016

Answer (score 3):

Someone I know had her Intel AC Wireless 9560 stop working randomly during the day (Ubuntu 18.04.2). After investigating the `dmesg` output, checking out the NetworkManager service, reinstalling `linux-firmware`, rebooting, etc., we tried loading up Windows 10 on the second partition. Even Windows 10 could not find the wireless.

I've seen a few forums mentioning this particular Intel wireless card model. <s>While this may be unhelpful, it's possible your card is broken; you may want to invest in a usb wifi or use ethernet and see if the card can be replaced (or do it yourself) [with another model].</s>

**She updated the BIOS and it started working again.**

Answer (score 0):

I think found a possible fix for it by opening Asus laptop and removing and reinserting Wifi Card did the job for me. I found it under SSD. worth giving a try if you are facing issue with both Bluetooth and Wifi. Old problem but still a nightmare.

Answer (score -1):

1. You should be sure then your HW support this stuff. It requires the newest HW.
2. Despite this stuff officially is supported since kernel 4.14+, by the fact you will avoid a lot of issues by using 4.16+ and the newest firmware.