# Intel Wireless-AC 9560 WiFi not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I recently finished my PC build using a motherboard with a built in Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 9560. While Bluetooth is working in Ubuntu 16.04, WiFi is still not working.

I tried installing the firmware provided on Intel's website https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html by copying iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz to lib/firmware/ but this does not seem to help.

Below is some more information that might be useful:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    5.535335] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.562102] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 33.610294.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.575320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    5.620228] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    5.620233] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    5.620273] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x2339
[    5.620274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    5.632149] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

sudo modprobe iwlwifi returns no output.

```
$rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ uname -a
Linux xx 4.13.0-43-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 12:56:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039359/cannot-detect-wireless-driver-intel-ac-wireless-9560-logs-included/1041577#1041577

Comment: Please try this out - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045407/wifi-on-asus-rog-gx501-works-with-ubuntu-18-04-fails-on-ubuntu-16-04-intel-wir. It worked for me with 18.04 -Sirish

Comment: Officially this stuff is supported since kernel 4.14+, but using 4.16+ will avoid a lot of issues. You run 4.13. Also, this stuff requires very specific HW.

Comment: @tdep did you ever get this working? I have exact same errors in `dmesg` on 16.04.

Comment: The question that this is claimed to be a duplicate of is about another error code, -110 instead of -5.