# WiFi on ASUS ROG GX501 works with Ubuntu 18.04, fails on Ubuntu 16.04 (Intel Wireless AC 9560)

Tags: wireless, 18.04, asus

I had no luck getting this to work with Ubuntu 16.04, and I would like to.
But here is what I did to get to work on Ubuntu 18.04 (since 9560 requires 4.14+ kernel version according to Intel official rel.)

1. `sudo su`
2. `rm -f /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-9000*`
3. `wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz; tar -xvzf iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz; cp iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode /lib/firmware/`
4. `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`
5. Assign the code to REGDOMAIN in the file /etc/default/crda (intl. codes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)
6. reboot

Comment: I would like to know if anyone got it to work on 16.04

Comment: Same issue here I may try this solution... no other updates on this?