# Thinkpad Carbon X1 2019 (gen7) Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, lenovo, thinkpad

Hardware: Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon X1 2019, using an Intel AC 9560 wireless module

Upon installing Ubuntu 18.04, I discovered that my Wi-Fi worked while installing Ubuntu, but did not after I restarted. It turns out that this problem occurs during the update process. Turns out it was the kernel! Worked on 5.3.0-28 but broken on 5.3.0-40

Specifically, you know you have the problem I experienced if you see the following behavior:

-The Wi-Fi settings page indicates that it cannot find a wireless module.

-You were able to see Wi-Fi networks while installing Ubuntu

-If you reboot Ubuntu using "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" at the startup screen and select an older kernel version (not recovery mode), your wireless works again

Comment: Hello Ryan. It is great of you to share the solution to this problem. We would appreciate it however, if you could keep the question and answer structure of the site. It is ok to post a question and then answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Solved problem by removing the offending updated kernel (`sudo apt purge linux-image-5.3.0-40-generic`) and swearing not to update my kernel in the future (judge me, I know!)

If someone wants to dig in and try to solve the issue in a more graceful way, then have at it! This is satisfactory for me.

Other possibly relevant links:

- [Cannot detect wireless driver intel ac wireless 9560 [logs included]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039359/cannot-detect-wireless-driver-intel-ac-wireless-9560-logs-included/1041577#1041577)
- [Intel Wireless-AC 9560 WiFi not working in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044284/intel-wireless-ac-9560-wifi-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201904-26993
- [driver intel ac wireless 9560 Ubuntu 18](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054012/driver-intel-ac-wireless-9560-ubuntu-18)
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400595
- [WiFi on ASUS ROG GX501 works with Ubuntu 18.04, fails on Ubuntu 16.04 (Intel Wireless AC 9560)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045407/wifi-on-asus-rog-gx501-works-with-ubuntu-18-04-fails-on-ubuntu-16-04-intel-wir)

<sup>*This answer was originally posted by Ryan Monroe [inside the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1211699/1).*</sup>