# driver intel ac wireless 9560 Ubuntu 18

Tags: wireless, 18.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18 on my new Legion Y530 laptop that has a Intel AC Wireless 9560. I know the hardware works as my windows boot drive connects fine. However the live environment does not detect internet (it says off and on button does nothing). The installer also does not detect my network. I'm hesistant to install if I can't connect to internet, what are the recommended steps to proceed and get my wi fi working, and is this not possible without actually installing?

Comment: Likely not possible without installing but installing with an internet connection has been causing some issues lately, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and post the results for the wireless script.

Comment: @Jeremy31 are you recommending I install without an internet connection and then plug in LAN afterwards? Would a manual installation of the driver perhaps fix it?

Comment: Yes, do the entire install without internet

Answer (score 1):

You can find the firmware for your wifi adapter here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

1. Click on the link for your wifi adapter.
2. Go to the Downloads folder.
3. Right click the .tgz file.
4. Choose extract here.
5. Copy the contents of the folder to /lib/firmware (you can click on 'other locations / Computer to find the directory.

Comment: I'll probably install and try this, but so I understand, is it normal this driver 9560 would not be present in live mode and or ubuntu 18.04 installer prior to install? I guess I'll just have to try to find out, but wondered if this is a known issue or omission.

Comment: I'm not an expert but according to this site ( https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi ) the drivers should be there since kernel 4.14, I believe Ubuntu 18.04 is using kernel 4.15.

Comment: Hi, it would be useful if you could provide the step by step commands that a user can copy and paste , in your answer instead of quoted text saying copy to this location.

Comment: I tested Fedora 28 and Kubuntu 18, I figured that would rule out Rufus 3.1/USB corruption and Kernel version (I believe Fedora is 4.17). Same issue/error, no wireless connection detected at all. Can I install a driver in the live environment?

Comment: What are being referred to above as 'drivers' are actually firmware files. The needed driver `iwlwifi` is already included in Ubuntu 18.04. Do the logs complain about missing firmware? `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 whole computer died (likely unrelated), I'll get back on this thread in a few days once Lenovo has fixed it.

Comment: @chili555, so I checked my lib/firmware and I already have iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode which is the file I downloaded from intel for their linux support. I'm at a total loss what to try next. I ran the wireless info script suggested on the thread, not sure if any info there is useful.

Comment: Where is the result of the wireless script? What is most useful is the dmesg I requested above.

Comment: Well, I returned the laptop, so I'm not sure I can continue troubleshooting, any way to close thread?

Comment: this somewhat pointed me in the right direction, however according the site the latest firmware for Intel Wireless-AC 9560 is `iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34` however Linux 5.15 already contains `iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46`
additionally in practice it loads `iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-xx` where `xx` is the latest supported version, on Linux 5.15 `iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55` works

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to play with this stuff using kernels before 4.16+. You use 4.15. Also, this stuff is extremely tricky.