# Problem while installing iwlwifi on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, iwlwifi

I'm a new one on Ubuntu and using UP BOARD with Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it.

I install iwlwifi according to this: https://github.com/HappyZ/iw_intel8260_localization/wiki/Enable-802.11mc-FTM-on-Intel-8260

While installing, after " sudo make -j4 ", I got many " symbolmap: 00000001: invalid section ".

just like this :

```
symbolmap: 00000001: invalid section
  CC [M]  /lib/firmware/backport-iwlwifi/net/mac80211/aes_gcm.o
symbolmap: 00000001: invalid section
  CC [M]  /lib/firmware/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/ctxt-info.o
symbolmap: 00000001: invalid section
  CC [M]  /lib/firmware/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans-gen2.o
  CC [M]  /lib/firmware/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/tx-gen2.o
  CC [M]  /lib/firmware/backport-iwlwifi/net/mac80211/aes_cmac.o
symbolmap: 00000001: invalid section
  CC [M]  /lib/firmware/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/trans_slave/shared.o
symbolmap: 00000001: invalid section
  CC [M]  /lib/firmware/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/trans_slave/sdio_drv.o
  CC [M]  /lib/firmware/backport-iwlwifi/net/mac80211/aes_gmac.o
symbolmap: 00000001: invalid section
```

I don't know it is whether a error or a normal situation.

After " sudo make install ", I got

```
$ sudo make install
INSTALL /lib/firmware/backport-iwlwifi/compat/compat.ko
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
```

But according to the guide, it is fine.

When I reboot, I got

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -a iwlwifi
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 kernel: [   10.400932] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 kernel: [   10.400934] iwlwifi-stack-public:release/LinuxCore30:6410:b52d6444
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 kernel: [   10.447909] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 kernel: [   10.460412] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 kernel: [   10.468110] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 kernel: [   10.468420] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 kernel: [   10.481075] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.560484.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 kernel: [   10.512214] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 kernel: [   10.583687] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: 38:de:ad:27:d0:e9
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 kernel: [   10.803541] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
Dec 12 09:36:33 vector-UP-APL01 NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1576114593.5811] rfkill1: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.3/0000:04:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)
```

When I go through the rest of the tutorial, it all shows up right, except that the final result is different than expected.

It shows

```
Target: 38:de:ad:27:d0:e9, status: 4, rtt: 0 psec, distance: 0 cm
```

but not

```
status: 0
```

which means I failed. According to the author, I redid these steps, but still failed.

Please, what can I do ?

I looked up related topics and tried some solutions.

According to [Cannot detect wireless driver intel ac wireless 9560 [logs included]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039359/cannot-detect-wireless-driver-intel-ac-wireless-9560-logs-included), I did:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

And after reboot, I got this:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   10.362192] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   10.362193] iwlwifi-stack-public:release/LinuxCore30:6410:b52d6444
[   10.410275] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   10.435415] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[   10.437919] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.441308] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.470903] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.560484.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   10.508139] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[   10.582355] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: 38:de:ad:27:d0:e9
[   10.669805] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   10.743291] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
```

It seems that it doesn't work.

Besides, after the upgrade, my firmware files include:

```
iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
```

Comment: All works well. I don't see any problems. Wireless is detected, firmware loaded and interface created.

Comment: Are these three errors right? And when I'm done with all the steps，I got 
"status: 4" but not "status: 0"

Comment: The errors are OK. The driver tries to load all firmware even if it doesn't exist yet. Now all works. But generally it wasn't a good idea to install backports. The HWE 4.15 kernel supports this adapter without tinkering with backports.

Comment: Another problem is that every time when I reboot, my WIFI doesn't work, which means there is no WIFI in the list. Meantime, I found the "wlp4s0" disappeared. But when I cut off the power and repower it, they came back again. Is this a normal situation?

Comment: This is not normal. But that is another question. I suggest to remove backports, install HWE, if not installed and test. If there arre problems, ask.

Comment: And I have restored the kernel version to 4.13 according to the guide, hope it's helpful. I'm sorry I can't follow you, does the HWE can fix the WIFI? Or can it eliminate the above errors?

Comment: The current HWE is 4.15. I have this adapter and it works.

Comment: Does it means I should upgrade kernel version to 4.15 before install HWE? I remember I got many serious errors in the version of 4.15 when I did these steps.

Comment: 4.13 is also a HWE, but an old one. So simply update your system and you should be on 4.15. Did you ever install updates?

Comment: I did "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade".

Comment: It should have installed the 4.15 kernel unless something wrong is with you system.

Comment: But the link above tells me "make sure your kernel is using 4.13 not 4.15". And I did meet many errors in the version of 4.15.

Comment: The above link was written when there was no 4.15 yet. ))

Comment: Really? Did not the author edit on 2019.4.12?

Comment: Is it necessary for me to upgrade the kernel version to 4.15? And do I need to uninstall the backports? :)

Comment: I don't know what you installed about kernels. All I can say that I am using a ;atop with Ubuntu 16.04 the same wireless adapter and the 4.15 official HWE kernel with no problems.

Comment: The virtual kernel version of the Ubuntu is 4.15, too. After I met many serious errors, I restored the kernel version to 4.13 as the link command. And those serious errors disappeared, so I think the version 4.13 is the right kernel version for it. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for tolerating my poor English expression and helping me to answer it enthusiastically. :)

Comment: No problem, but you've chosen a wrong solution. `4.13` is EoL, etc. What kind of "many errors" with 4.15 is unclear. So cheers.

Comment: If, as you said, the above problems do not exist at all, then I have to find other reasons.