# Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 5491

Tags: dell, inspiron

Has anyone managed to install Ubuntu 18.04 or 19.10 on Dell Inspiron 5491 2-in-1 with intel i5-10210u?

I tried the "try it without installing option" and the WiFi adapted was not detected, does the same thing happen after the installation?

Also, if you have it installed on the same computer, it would be really helpful if you could mention any problems, or things not working with Ubuntu?

Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest looking at troubleshooting doco, eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide where the device recognition & operation section (3 troubleshooting) is most helpful as allows discover of chipset in use which usually allows easy correction.  I don't know your device but dell have history of changing components during life of all but short-lived products mandating their use of service-tag more than model info for....  Once you have chipset you can search online or we can provide help too

Comment: If your WiFi chip was not detected, then you will almost certainly have the same problem on the installed system.

Comment: @guiverc This is my WiFi chip: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560. The WiFi settings don't even show up in settings.

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039359/cannot-detect-wireless-driver-intel-ac-wireless-9560-logs-included  -- key to me was the firmware update; you can't have that on the 'live' system, so if that's your issue once you have installed, and fully-upgraded - the issue will resolve (if that's the issue; firmware is loaded on booting thus cannot help 'live' or install media itself).  That may not be your issue though 19.10, updating BIOS fixed another users issue I see too.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your help. So I am assuming I would still need internet connection (through Ethernet) after the installation for firmware update to happen, or it happens on its own after the installation?

Comment: Yes you'll need to use ethernet to `apt full-upgrade` to get the updates (you could walk them to your box via thumb-drive, but that's a LOAD more work), but once installed & rebooted (firmware is loaded at boot time) you can use wireless from then on I'd hope if what I mentioned last comment; did you try 18.04.4 media? (you didn't specify what 18.04 media you tried; 18.04.4 is newer than 19.10)

Comment: @guiverc makes sense, thanks a lot. I had 18.04.3 on my old laptop but I only tried 19.10 on my new laptop. https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop, I do not see 18.04.4 on here, would I have to download it from somewhere else? and would you say it is more stable than 19.10?

Comment: Officially 18.04.4 is released on Thursday (6-Feb-2020); RC (release candidate is currently is all that's available; http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/410/builds).  Yes 18.04.3 is more stable (it'll update to 18.04.4 after install and first update), however also officially 19.10 (or 19.10.1 on r.pi.4) is more stable than 18.04.4 new installs (until official release anyway; if problems are detected in testing, a new RC will be spun; the 18.04.4 just has updates that won't exist in older 18.04.3/19.10(.x) media available at boot

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the explanation. I will probably go for 18.04.4 then.

Answer (score 0):

No I have installed ubuntu on this device, and dual booted windows, and everything seems to work, as far as Iv'e seen yet, I did custom partitions, and I think selected optional drivers or more, I also went to a site online and got driver for finger scanner, goodix, fingerprint sign in works, on old versions of ubuntu do sudo apt-upgrade or sudo apt-update, choose to install fingerprint from drop box now fingerprint authentication works, also fingerprint, also is only suppoted on ubuntu, not kubuntu, other ones i'm not sure of, hope I helped.

Comment: Does the WiFi/WLAN adapter work for you, too?

Comment: I don't see the answer here. The question question isn't clear.

Answer (score -1):

I installed ubuntu 18.04 just to find that Ubuntu doesn't have necessary drivers to support the hardware of inspiron 5491. None of the wifi, sound, etc. works.
But manjaro is the best alternative, and I surely recommend to go for it.